# Tilted 2PT Perspective Cube - Eye Level Line Placement?

Tags: drawing, perspective

When drawing a cube in 2 point perspective you would normally have the horizon line flat, a horizontal line going across the page.

But if I was to rotate the current cube and tilt it 45 degrees clockwise. Would that mean I have to draw the horizon line tilted?

Just trying to figure out how to draw 2 point perspective cubes that are tilted and which is the correct way to go about it.

Please help, thanks.

Comment: Project from the side.

Comment: What do you mean by that?